# how to look for an element in nested list in parallel

Tags: python, list, set, indices

I have a list of elements `A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` and a nested list `B = [{'55','a'}, {'4','t'}, {'x','y','zx'}, {'b','d'}, {'66','c'}]`.
In addition, each element can appear only in one sub-list of `B`.

I want to find, for each element from `A`, the index of the sub-list from `B` that contains it (`[0, 3, 4, 3]`). Assume that all the elements from `A` appear somewhere in `B`.

Using a nested loop isn't practical for the size of my data.

Comment: The output you expect is unclear, can you provide it? Also are you "sublists" in B rather sets?

Comment: for:
`A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` and 
`B = [{'55','a'}, {'4','t'}, {'x','y','zx'}, {'b','d'}, {'66','c'}]`
The desired answer would be `[0,3,4,3]`.
Yes, I actually have sets in `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First build a dictionary of the positions in B for each item, then use a list comprehension on A:

```
d = {k:i for i,s in enumerate(B) for k in s}
# {'55': 0, 'a': 0, 't': 1, '4': 1,
#  'zx': 2, 'y': 2, 'x': 2, 'd': 3,
#  'b': 3, 'c': 4, '66': 4}

out = [d[x] for x in A]
```

Or, if you are not sure that all elements of A are in B:

```
out = [d.get(x, -1) for x in A]
```

Output:

```
[0, 3, 4, 3]
```

Used input:

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
B = [{'55','a'}, {'4','t'}, {'x','y','zx'}, {'b','d'}, {'66','c'}]
```